# VI functionality in the code editor for coding questions/answers

Tags: feature-request

It could be a challenging, if not impossible task. YET As a developer, I like to type code in VI, hence I want the SO to have VI like functionalities... and perhaps other editors like pico, nano, emacs.

yes -- we can cut-and-paste. But if  you implement it, we won't have to.

Thoughts?

too impossible?

Comment: I want emacs abilities. (Sorry, I really couldn't resist. Please don't take that seriously!)

Comment: I was going to make a joke, but surprisingly I found http://emacs.wordpress.com/2007/02/23/emacs-friendly-firefox/
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Emacs_Keybindings_%28Firefox%29
http://bc.tech.coop/blog/060529.html

Comment: http://vian.sourceforge.net/

Comment: You could go ask your local Greasy Monkey for help.

Comment: Do you mean "vi"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`vimperator`](http://vimperator.mozdev.org/) for Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

The editor in SO is not made for writing programs.

VI would be totally inappropriate for the intended use of the editor.

Answer (score 0):

What part of vi do you want? Modal editing? Specific commands?

I've little doubt this could be accomplished using Greasemonkey for the handful of users foolhardy enough to write large amounts of code in a tiny browser textarea...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [It's All Text!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4125) addon for firefox, which lets you use any external editor of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely.  The fact that the textarea doesn't support emacs commands is infuriating.  Do you know how many times I've wanted to check my email, talk to an Eliza, and play Tetris *all at the same time* while writing an answer on SO?  I can't stress enough how important it is that the SO Team immediately drop whatever else they're doing (probably removing a useful feature, amirite?) and get to work on porting emacs to Javascript.